# What is this plant's scientific name?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This is the picture of a tree in my college's botanical garden.[image]

First I thought it to be a banana tree for its leaves but then seeing its lower part, I don't think it is a banana tree. So what is it's scientific name? I am just curious. Is it any hybrid or something like that plant?

Edit: This tree is from Bangladesh in South Asia. This tree is approximately 9-10 feet (I think, I cannot go near the tree). This picture is from Spring season.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide your location and the approximate size of the plant. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for guidelines for writing *well-received* [tag:species-identification] questions. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of this plant is: 
**Ravenala madagascariensis** 
Check: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenala)

[image]

Comment: It is not a banana . I have seen them but don't know the name.

Comment: @blacksmith37 edited my answer

Comment: @Muath It's plant not planet